# Make ESlint errors in VSCode show when cursor is placed on them

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I have installed the eslint extension for vscode. When it catches an error or warning it underlines the relevant code with a green or red line. If I use the mouse cursor to hover over the warning it will spawn a popup message with specifics of the error. Is it possible to have this error message spawn when the cursor is over the error so I don't have to use the mouse?

Comment: Did you open an issue about it? I would +1 that

Comment: @Ben found some relevant discussion here github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a "Show Fixes" feature in VS Code.

When the cursor is over the issue, a little light bulb is shown. If it is cicked or its hotkey (Ctrl+.) is pressed, it implicitly describes the error (e.g. "Fix this no-multi-spaces problem").

It's not as verbose as the description on hover but probably better then nothing and with the hotkey it can be activated without using the mouse.

**EDIT**

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288439/make-eslint-errors-in-vscode-show-when-cursor-is-placed-on-them/49132043#comment68464269_40288439), F8 works better, it jumps to the next error (which is the current if the cursor is on it) and shows the full description.

Comment: F8 is working really well for me. You should update your answer with `F8` for Next Error and `Shift + F8` for Previous Error.